# Losing MathML when converting from HTML to Docx using LibreOffice

Tags: xhtml, docx, libreoffice, jodconverter, unoconv

I am using LibreOffice to convert a .docx file to an XHTML file. Mathematics is converted to MathML.

My plan is to use LibreOffice in headless mode (or tools based on it) to convert back the XHTML file to a Docx file but after this conversion mathematics is rendered as plain text, even when I convert to an ODT file.

Is this possible or back conversion does not support OOML (MathML)?

Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.